# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los ancestros de cualquier nodo en un árbol binario?

Tags: java, nodos

Estoy tratando de hacer un método para obtener los ancestros de un nodo X en un árbol binario,
creo que el metodo es recursivo, pero no lo he podido hacer correctamente, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: paso1: si el nodo no tiene padre terminamos, paso 2: checando su padre y el padre de este, paso 3: haz el paso 2.. dame mis puntos :3